# Checking if a file is a text file without using -T?

Tags: perl

Title is pretty self explanatory, are there file testing functions in perl or is there a built in module that allows file testing operations?

Comment: Why is it not ok to use -T?

Comment: [`perldoc -f -X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) to see available file test operators, although I'd also like to know why you don't want to use `-T`.

Comment: i've been asked to not use external commands

Comment: The file test operators are not external commands, they're Perl builtins.

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-issue as `-T` like all of the file test operators are perl builtins.

They are documented here: [`perldoc -X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

> - `-X FILEHANDLE`
> - `-X EXPR`
> - `-X DIRHANDLE`
> - `-X`
>
>   A file test, where X is one of the letters listed below. This unary operator takes one argument, either a filename, a filehandle, or a dirhandle, and tests the associated file to see if something is true about it. If the argument is omitted, tests `$_` , except for `-t` , which tests `STDIN`. Unless otherwise documented, it returns `1` for true and `''` for false, or the undefined value if the file doesn't exist. Despite the funny names, precedence is the same as any other named unary operator.
>
>   ...
>
>   `-T`  File is an ASCII text file (heuristic guess).
>
>   `-B`  File is a "binary" file (opposite of `-T`).

Answer (score 0):

The "file test" functions available in Perl are part of the programming language itself. Based on what you're saying and from the comments on this page, it may be that you have been "asked not to use external commands" because someone thinks that the -T flag is relying on something that belongs to the underlying environment and not the Perl language.

-T is part of the -X file test unary operators which are inherent to Perl:

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html

Underlying the -T operator (specifically) is the function `pp_fttext`, which lives in `pp_sys.c`. These are part of the underlying code that comprises Perl, and you can verify this by looking in the root directory of the Perl source distribution:

http://www.perl.org/get.html

It may be the only way to do what you were originally asking (how to do this without -T) might be to do what you were asked not to do (use something external to Perl to perform the test).